# Is it possible host a React app on let's say mydomain.com and Strapi admin dashboard on mydomain.com/admin?

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, strapi, web-development-server

I am developing a React app using Strapi as CMS.
I have hosted my React app on Netlify and Strapi have been deployed to Render.
I want to use the same domain for my Frontend and Server.

I was not able to find any solution.

Comment: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/deployment/nginx-proxy